# Unresolved external symbol in QT creator 5

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm getting an unresolved external symbol in QT creator 5. The problem with this is that I started getting this error after having already used these functions without issue before. I did a bit of refactoring, and then, boom, unresolved external symbol. I attempted to follow many of the other suggestions for other people encountering the same issue with QT Creator 5, but that hasn't seemed to resolve my issue.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QTableWidget::setRowCount(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_?setRowCount@QTableWidget@@QEAAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QTableWidget::setColumnCount(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_?setColumnCount@QTableWidget@@QEAAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
```

And I get those errors when compiling my mainwindow.cpp file. The error message appears to say "file not found: mainwindow.obj" when you click on the error message in the IDE. However, I went poking around in the build folder, and the file is there. I've deleted the build folder and rebuilt. I tried "unfactoring" a bit to get my project into the same state it was in before I mad ethese changes, but that didn't help anything. I tried running qmake again, and that didn't help. Any other suggestions?

I'm including the mainwindow.cpp file, mainwindow.h, and the .pro file to show how I'm using them.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <qtreewidget.h>
#include <QtDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    CurrentlySelectedAccount( nullptr )
{
    financials::TheCalculator* calc = new financials::TheCalculator();

    QString filename( "C:\\source\\QT_Projects\\FinancialExplorer\\InputFinancials.ini" );
    calc->ParseInputFile( filename );
    this->CurrentSimulation = calc;

    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->Accounts->setAnimated( true );

    auto AccountsMap = calc->GetAccounts();
    auto iter = AccountsMap.begin();
    QTreeWidget* accounts = ui->Accounts;
    bool isFirst = true;
    auto selectedIter = AccountsMap.begin();
    while( iter != AccountsMap.end() )
    {
        QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem( accounts, 2 ); // 2 means "Don't show expander if no children"

        item->setText( 0, calc->GetName() );

        // add properties
        QTreeWidgetItem* StartDateItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( item, 0 );
        QString startDateLabel( "Start Date:" );
        startDateLabel.append( calc->GetStartDate().toString());
        StartDateItem->setText( 0, startDateLabel );

        QTreeWidgetItem* EndDateItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( item, 0 );
        QString EndDateLabel( "End Date:" );
        EndDateLabel.append( calc->GetEndDate().toString());
        EndDateItem->setText( 0, EndDateLabel );

        QTreeWidgetItem* CurrentDateItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( item, 0 );
        QString CurrentDateLabel( "Current Date:" );
        CurrentDateLabel.append( calc->GetCurrentDate().toString());
        CurrentDateItem->setText( 0, CurrentDateLabel );

        // add accounts
        QTreeWidgetItem* accountsItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( item, 2 );
        accountsItem->setText( 0, "Accounts" );
        for( auto& account : calc->GetAccounts() )
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem* accItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( accountsItem, 2 );
            accItem->setText( 0, account.second.GetName() );
            accItem->setText( 1, "I'm an account description" );
        }

        // add events
        QTreeWidgetItem* eventsItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( item, 2 );
        eventsItem->setText( 0, "Events" );
        for( auto& event : calc->GetEvents() )
        {
            QTreeWidgetItem* eventItem = new QTreeWidgetItem( eventsItem, 2 );
            eventItem->setText( 0, event.GetName() );
            eventItem->setText( 1, "I'm an event description" );
        }
        item->setText(1, "I'm a description");
        if( isFirst )
        {
            item->setSelected( true );
            selectedIter = iter;
            isFirst = false;
        }
        ++iter;
    }

    connect(ui->Accounts,&QTreeWidget::itemClicked,this,&MainWindow::on_MyTree_itemClicked);

    RefreshTable();
}

void MainWindow::RefreshTable()
{
    financials::TheCalculator* calc = CurrentSimulation;
    if( calc != nullptr )
    {
        int lengthOfSimulation = calc->GetLengthOfSimulation();
        ui->Spreadsheet->setRowCount( lengthOfSimulation );
        int accountsSize = calc->GetAccounts().size();
        ui->Spreadsheet->setColumnCount( accountsSize );

        int rowIndex = 0;
        while( calc->IsRunning() )
        {
            QString value;
            auto accounts = calc->GetAccounts();
            auto accountsIter = accounts.begin();
            int colIndex = 0;
            while( accountsIter != accounts.end() )
            {
                value = QString::number(     (*accountsIter).second.GetCurrentBalance() );
                ui->Spreadsheet->setItem(rowIndex, colIndex++, new QTableWidgetItem( value ));
                ++accountsIter;
            }
            calc->IncrementMonth();
            ++rowIndex;
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_MyTree_itemClicked ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column     )
{
    qDebug() << "on_MyTree_itemClicked"
    << item->text(column);
    //to do somthing

    QString text = item->text(column);
    if( CurrentSimulation != nullptr )
    {
        auto iter = CurrentSimulation->GetAccounts().find( text );
        if( iter != CurrentSimulation->GetAccounts().end() )
        {
            if( CurrentAccountName != text )
            {
                CurrentAccountName = text;
                CurrentlySelectedAccount = &((*iter).second);
                RefreshTable();
            }
        }
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>
#include <QTableWidget>
#include "thecalculator.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void on_MyTree_itemClicked ( QTreeWidgetItem * item, int column );
    void Ondoubleclicktree(QModelIndex);
    void update(QModelIndex);
    void RefreshTable();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QString CurrentAccountName;
    financials::TheCalculator* CurrentSimulation;
    financials::Account* CurrentlySelectedAccount;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-08-26T18:06:52
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = FinancialExplorer
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    accounts.cpp \
    thecalculator.cpp \
    financials.cpp \
    events.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    accounts.h \
    financials.h \
    thecalculator.h \
    events.h \
    qstringhashfunction.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

DISTFILES += \
    InputFinancials.ini
```

Comment: Are you possibly mixing compilers, e.g. trying to use a Qt built with MinGW and compile your application with MSVC? That’s not possible.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the PRO file from before the refactoring?  What differences are there?

Comment: I had one case where I could never solve a similar situation. I eventually just moved the code to a clean project and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had one case just like you .Finally ,I found it was DefaultQtVersion and QtModules ,I should use msvc2015_64 instead of msvc2015 and choose the modules with Serial Port.